# How to embed LinkedIn Profile in VueJs Component

Tags: vue.js

I am using VueJS to build a website and I got to the point where I want to include my embedded profile into a page/Component in Vue. It seems to work only if I refresh the page. When I navigate from other pages to this page it is not displayed.
In my `public/index.html` I included LinkedIn Library Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer></script>
```

In my component:

```html
<template>
<!-- some other code -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-sm-center">
        <div class="LI-profile-badge" data-version="v1" data-size="medium" data-locale="en_US" data-type="vertical" data-theme="dark" data-vanity="nicolae-orlov">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I saw some info that I need to reload the component to force it to re-render but I am not sure how. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a script tag only on a specific component, you can use [PostScribe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postscribe) to render a script after load.

After installing (`npm i postscribe --save`) and importing (`import postscribe from 'postscribe'`), you can add your script tag in the mounted lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
  postscribe('#linkedin', '<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js"><\/script>')
}
```

where `#linkedin` refers to the ID of your profile badge element (add an ID if necessary)

Your linkedin badge should now be embedded in your Vue component.

Comment: Hi Julia, thank you for your answer, this might work however I fixed it in a different way. I was able to modify LinkedIn library to export it as a function and in my vue component to import it and in lifecycle hook `created` to call it. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the javascript by injecting script into head and then adding the html into the respective component. This is how you can inject javascript directly into head from the component.

```js
<script>
export default {
    head(){
        return{
            script : [
                {
                    src: 
                        'https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js',
                    type:
                        'text/javascript'
                } 
            ],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```